# Forward slash in string split regexp in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have this code that doesn't work:

```
val words = body.split("""[\s\.,!\?:;"()<>\[\]#$=-\/]+""")
```

Whenever I run it I got error:

[image: error]

How this can be fixed?

Comment: move `-` to the end of character class: `[...-]`.

Comment: As @AndreyTyukin said. Just do like this `[\s\.,!\?:;"()<>\[\]#$=\/-]+`

Comment: Thanks guys, can you make it an answer?